Is Taking Books from a Synagogue Theft?
If someone works in a Talmud Torah in a shul, would a person be able to take and make use of any of the sefarim (books) or would that be considered stealing?
Imagine if the scenario is without prior consent. Is taking something from a bet knesset- even if you’re part of the community- considered as theft?

Welcome to MiYodeya ESC and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

I'm not sure I understand the two sides of the question. What would be the possible justification for taking books which belong to someone else? Could you take 30 books there? 20 books? 10?

Are they in a free books shelf or genizah ?

@ESC - please note I have reworded the question as a more general rather than personal query to avoid it going against the terms of Mi Yodeya and being viewed as someone seeking a personal psak (ruling)

What do you mean "take"?  Just pick up and read?  Take it home for a while?  Take it home and never return it?

Regarding the tag, gezel is not stealing in secret, gezel  means forcibly taking an object from someone, usually with weapons. A better tag would be geneiva

B"H
Stealing (Geneiva) is defined in halacha (Rambam, Shulchan Aruch) as taking an item without permission from the original owner, even if one intends to give it back.
There's no exception for a synagogue that I'm aware of
If the book is lying around on the street in an unguarded area near the synagogue or placed in geniza, that would be another story (possibly considered ownerless because they wouldn't expect to still have it if it's left in unguarded area and might be considered yeush, but ask a rav before acting on that).
But if it's on the shelf inside the actual synagogue itself, then that's definitely stealing.

Even though one's intentions may be pure, it is definitely not the correct thing to do.
I don't know if it qualifies as "stealing" if they are intending to return it, but it is also not the right thing to do without first gaining express permission.
There is a famous piece from the Steipler (Rav Yaakov Yisrael Kanievsky) brought in his Karyana D’Igarta, letter 189 which is often printed in Yeshivos and the like...

ודאי מדת אכזריות ורשע הוא להטיל על אחרים מה שהוא הוציא ממקומו וכל שכן להטיל על תלמיד חכם השוקד על התורה את המוטל על עצמו
It is definitely a cruel and evil trait to place on others when one takes out (a sefer) from its place (and does not return it afterwards), and all the more so when it happens to a wise man who is diligent about Torah (and will waste his time looking for a sefer).

